# php email form still not working although code apparently correct

Tags: php, email

I made the suggested changes to the sendemail.php file, so the entire file now contains...

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'mail@URLREMOVED.co.uk';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
die;
```

After attempting another test message, nothing was received in my email inbox at all.

Comment: you're constantly overwriting the headers. Go back to the manual on `mail()`.

Comment: *"The code provided includes changes made to the original code after advice on this forum last night."* - I'd sure like to see that.

Comment: Or switch to [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which is easier to work with

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace :

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers = "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers = "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
$headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";
```

**with**

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";
```

its failing because you did not set your $`headers` correctly, you override your headers, on each line just after you assigned a value, the next line you override previous value.

Comment: *"Try"* - doesn't explain why it was failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated

Comment: That is much better ;-) this for both the OP and for future visitors.